# Where does Oracle store table comments?

Tags: sql, oracle

Just in case the question is not clear enough.

I have most tables commented with stuff like this:

```
COMMENT ON TABLE owner.employee IS 'Stores the blabla';
```

And would be nice to search over my db by looking in the tables comments (there're like 2k tables, not my fault)

Answer (score 6):

The system views `ALL_TAB_COMMENTS` and `USER_TAB_COMMENTS` contain table comments and `ALL_COL_COMMENTS` and `USER_COL_COMMENTS` has columns comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this statement:

```
-- All tables inside my user  
select table_name, comments from user_tab_comments

-- All tables for all users:  
select table_name, comments from all_tab_comments
```